# Cómo puedo conseguir que el texto se mueva con el slider?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, slider

Tengo un *slider* hecho solo con *html* y *css*. Las imágenes se mueven correctamente pero el texto relacionado con cada una de ellas no. Aparece uno encima de otro superpuesto y sin animación. En cada "diapositiva" debería haber una imagen y el texto relacionado encima.

Sé que el problema está con la clase encima y el `position:absolute`, pero si no, no consigo darle una posición fija con respecto a el `div "banerosoa"`. Estoy intentando convertir un simple destacado en un slider y se me esta yendo de las manos. Solicito un alma caritativa.

El código es el siguiente: (creo que no me dejo nada sin meter en el post)

El html lleva bootstrap y poco mas

```html
<section id="banner">
    <style type="text/css">
        .slider {
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .slider ul {
            display: flex;
            padding: 0;
            width: 400%;
            animation: cambio 20s infinite alternate linear;
        }
        .slider li {
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none;
        }
        .slider img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        @keyframes cambio {
            0% {margin-left: 0;}
            20% {margin-left: 0;}
            25% {margin-left: -100%;}
            45% {margin-left: -100%;}
            50% {margin-left: -200%;}
            70% {margin-left: -200%;}
            75% {margin-left: -300%;}
            100% {margin-left: -300%;}
        }
    </style>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul>
            <li>
                @php
                    $destacado = $destacadok[0];
                @endphp
                    <div class="col-lg-12 banerosoa" style="background-image: url(/img/imagen1.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 encima">
                    <a href="/es/noticia/{{$destacado->sluges}}"><h2>Noticia1</h2></a>
                    <h5>redactor1</h5>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                @php
                    $destacado = $destacadok[1];
                @endphp
                    <div class="col-lg-12 banerosoa" style="background-image: url(/img/imagen1.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 encima">
                    <a href="/es/noticia/{{$destacado->sluges}}"><h2>Noticia1</h2></a>
                    <h5>redactor1</h5>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                @php
                    $destacado = $destacadok[2];
                @endphp
                    <div class="col-lg-12 banerosoa" style="background-image: url(/img/imagen1.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 encima">
                    <a href="/es/noticia/{{$destacado->sluges}}"><h2>Noticia1</h2></a>
                    <h5>redactor1</h5>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                @php
                    $destacado = $destacadok[3];
                @endphp
                    <div class="col-lg-12 banerosoa" style="background-image: url(/img/imagen1.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 encima">
                    <a href="/es/noticia/{{$destacado->sluges}}"><h2>Noticia1</h2></a>
                    <h5>redactor1</h5>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Y el css restante es este:

```css
.encima{
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:#fff !important;
}

.encima a{
    color:#fff;
}

.banerosoa{
    width:100%;
    height:650px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el `position: absolute` que le has dado al elemento `.encima`, como bien has determinado.

Un elemento con `position: absolute` se posiciona respecto al primer ancestro que se encuentre con `position: relative`. De no encontrar ninguno tomará los límites que le de el **layout** del dispositivo donde se visualice.

Sin poder reproducir tu código te diría que la solución la tienes en dar al elemento `.banerosoa` un `position: relative` para que el texto se posicione respecto al `<div>` que lo contiene para que al moverse este, le acompañe.

```
.banerosoa{
    width:100%;
    height:650px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```